# How do I export a function from an imported module?

Tags: haskell, module

```
module Hart
  ( module Hart
  )
 where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (runReaderT, ReaderT, ask)
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
```

I currently have the above defined. How can I export **only** the `ask` function from `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` in addition to the `Hart` module?

I was thinking I could do the below - but it generates an error:

```
module Hart
  ( module Hart
  , module Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ask)
  ) where
```

Comment: Um, `module Hart
  ( module Hart
  , ask
  )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leftaroundabout mentioned in the comments, to re-export functions, you simply include that function in your export list:

```
module Hart 
  ( module Hart
  , ask 
  ) where 
...
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ask)
```

This will also work for qualified imports with the caveat that the namespace is not captured in the export.

```
module Hart 
  ( module Hart
  , ask 
  , T.null
  ) where 
...
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ask)
import qualified Data.Text as T
```

And in some other file:

```
  module Other where 

  import Hart (ask, null)
```